# How to show results in a column in the dialogbox?

Tags: java, dialog

I've written a program that ads 5 to all the elements in a given array of integers. When it's done, it prints out the elements one after another in the console. Here is the code:

```
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;

public class arrays {
   public static void main(String[] arg){
      int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

      change(array);

      for (int y : array)
         System.out.println(y);
   }
   public static void change(int x[]){
      for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
         x[i] = x[i] + 5;
   }
}
```

Result:

```
6
7
8
9
10
```

**Question:** Instead of using `System.out.println(y)`, I want to use `showMessageDialog(null, y)` in order to print all the integers in a column in one dialog box, without having to press enter and only show one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepare your String:

```
String str = "";
for (int y : array){
    str += String.valueOf(y) + "\n";
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,str);
```